Module not found error when using ScrapeGraphAI
I am doing a simple example using ScrapeGraphAI, found on this link ScrapeGraphAI Github.
I have installed the packages in the virtual environment, as shown in the link:
pip install scrapegraphai

playwright install

But when I run the code
from scrapegraphai.graphs import SmartScraperGraph

I get the following error message:
File "C:\...\Python\ScrapeGraphAI\scrapegraphai.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapegraphai.graphs import SmartScraperGraph
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapegraphai.graphs'; 'scrapegraphai' is not a package

What could be the problem if everything is installed properly?

Do not give your python file the same name as the package. Your file is named scrapegraphai.py, hence from scrapegraphai ... tries to load from that file and not from the actual package. Just rename your file with your normal code.
